# Splitting string into groups of "x" length

Tags: python

I was wondering, if I had a string that was read from a text file, what would be the most efficient way of splitting it into groups of 5 characters? For example:

I have a text file called dna.txt, and its contents are:

```
>human
ACCGTGAAAAACGTGAGTATA
>mouse
ACCAAAAGTGTAT
```

I then have a Python script that will store the 2nd and 4th lines of the text file.

```
import linecache
f = open("dna.txt")
sequence_1 = linecache.getline('dna.txt', 2)
sequence_2 = linecache.getline('dna.txt', 4)
f.close()
```

The goal is for the program to print out:

```
>human
ACCGT
GAAAA
ACGTG
AGTAT
A
>mouse
ACCAA
AAGTG
TAT
```

Like I said before, I've been trying to come up with an efficient way of breaking the 2 strings, but with no luck. Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you try any slicing strategies?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks

Comment: No. I'm new to Python and don't really know how to approach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> human = 'ACCGTGAAAAACGTGAGTATA'
>>> mouse = 'ACCAAAAGTGTAT'
>>> import re
>>> def format_dna(s):
...     return re.sub(r'(.{5})(?!$)', r'\g<1>\n', s)
...
>>> print(format_dna(human))
ACCGT
GAAAA
ACGTG
AGTAT
A
>>> print(format_dna(mouse))
ACCAA
AAGTG
TAT
```

[`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) does regular expression replacements in the string.

`(.{5})(?!$)` is the pattern to match. `\g<1>\n` is the pattern to substitute.

`.{5}` matches any five characters. With parens `(.{5})` it's a capture group.

`$` matches the end of the string. `(?!$)` is a negative lookahead assertion. This prevents the pattern from matching the last group if the string's length is a multiple of five (which would result in adding an unwanted newline at the end of the string).

`\g<1>` is a backreference that refers to the first (and only) capture group.

So this says: When you see five characters in a row (that aren't the last five), replace them with the five characters, plus a newline.

Comment: All of the    In [x]:   parts result in the error: End of Statement Expected, and Statement expected, found Py:COLON

Comment: Reformatted it to look like a standard python prompt.

Comment: It works, but could you explain the 5th line to me? Is that just purely for formatting?

Comment: Updated the answer to explain.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started:

```
human = "ACCGTGAAAAACGTGAGTATA"
print(' '.join(human[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(human), 5)))
```

It's easy to generalize this into a generator that takes `human` and `5` as arguments and yields the substrings:

```
def splitn(s, n):
    for i in range(0, len(s), n):
        yield s[i:i+n]

print(' '.join(splitn("ACCGTGAAAAACGTGAGTATA", 5)))
```

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Python 3, is that the proper format for it? Or is that for 2?

Comment: @Muffinman: The `In[x]:` and `Out[x]:` bits are IPython prompts: http://ipython.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Before using this, look at the other answers that were posted while I was writing this up.
This is a simple, and very sub-optimal algorithm.

Not super efficient but you could do it with simple loop.

```
str = "abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvwxyz"
length = len(str)
i = 0
subs = []
while (i < length):
    subs[i/5] = str[i:i+5]
    i += 5
```

This should end up with each index of subs containing five characters grouped.

Comment: subs[i/5] = str[i:i+5]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float

Comment: @Muffinman sorry, cast it to int. I/5 should always give you an int (0/5,5/5,10/5,etc)

Comment: @David not in python3 ... you need `3//5` for an int

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I know. It was simply an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily with a generator expression or a list comprehension in older versions of Python. For any string `s` and index `i` within the string the expression `s[i:i+5]` will evaluate to a substring of `s` of maximum length 5 starting at position `i`.

If `i+5` happens to point past the end of the string the slicing notation conveniently suppresses any index errors and just returns the longest string it can.

So the expression

```
[sequence_1[i:i+5] for i in range((0, len(sequence_1), 5)]
```

should give you a list of the substrings you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def groupdna(long_seq,size=5):
...     groups = itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(long_seq)]*size,fillvalue="")
...     return list(map("".join,groups))
...
>>> groupdna(human,5)
['ACCGT', 'GAAAA', 'ACGTG', 'AGTAT', 'A']
>>> groupdna(mouse,5)
['ACCAA', 'AAGTG', 'TAT']
>>>
```

is a fun way to do it :P

Comment: meh I just changed it to use izip_longest instead ... and broke it out into slightly more bytesize chunks

Comment: Yep tha will work except it is `zip_longest` in python 3

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = "ACCGTGAAAAACGTGAGTATA"

In [3]: print("\n".join(re.findall("\w{5}|\w+",s))) 
ACCGT
GAAAA
ACGTG
AGTAT
A
```

`re.findall("\w{5}|\w+",s)` finds 5 chars together or one or more chars together.

Some timings:

```
In [72]: %timeit "\n".join(groupdna(s,5))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.5 µs per loop

In [73]: timeit ('\n'.join(splitn(s, 5)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.22 µs per loop

In [74]: %timeit re.sub(r'(.{5})(?!$)', r'\g<1>\n', s)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.24 µs per loop

In [75]: %timeit ("\n".join(re.findall("\w{5}|\w+",s)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.16 µs per loop
```